# round( ) issue in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

Trying to figure out why round function does not work for hundredth decimal place.

```
int i=round(0.054545*100);
NSLog(@"Rounded value is %d",i);
Output: Rounded value is 5

int i=round(0.055*100);
NSLog(@"Rounded value is %d",i);
Output: Rounded value is 6
```

Any suggestion to round 0.0545*100 ~(0.055*100) to 6.

Comment: What would the rule be? Always round up? 5.45 _is_ closer to 5 than 6, so a bit unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: if less than 5 round down, 5 or more round up.

Comment: Is there a question here (other than why you didn't study the C definition of `round`?).

Comment: 5.45 is closer to 5 than it is to 6, so it rounds down to 5.  That’s the correct behavior.

Comment: If you'd like to round 5.45 up to 6, do `round(5.45 + 0.05)`.  (Or add 0.55 and use truncate.)

Comment: I edited my question, this will clear what i am trying to obtain. adding some constant to round up or down is not what i am looking for. I am trying to figure out round() up/down function works for  tenth decimal place but not on Hundredths decimal place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round function takes one order of magnitude less than the least significant digit that you want your output to round to and uses that to round. In this case, `5.45` is the same as `5.49` and `5.40` as the **hundredths** digit is insignificant. If I understand your question correctly, you want `5.44444444` to round down to `5` and `5.4444444445` to round up to `6`?

I think what you're looking for is a recursive rounding operation. You'd want to round `5.45` to `5.5` and then round `5.5` to `6`. In other words, you want to round the smallest non-zero digit then round the smallest non-zero digit of that output...repeat...until the last non-zero digit is the least significant digit you desire.

Comment: Yes, that is what i was trying to figure out. I was able solve it with  rounding twice.  
    firstRoundRounding=round(0.054545*1000);
    secondRoundRounding=  round([[NSNumber numberWithInt: firstRoundRounding] floatValue]/10);

Comment: Test this on a friend who owes you $5.45 but has only singles.  See if you can get him to give you $6.

Answer (score 0):

Add `0.1` to `5.45` before rounding it to make it to `6`.